# How to pass boolean into Material UI MenuItem value in react ts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx, react-tsx

I am new to react and am having some trouble passing a simple boolean value as a prop for the MenuItem in the material UI library. I don't think the solution is too complicated. Can someone let me know how I can resolve this error?

The Line that this error is point to is shown below:

```
<MenuItem value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>
```

The error looks like this:

```
  The last overload gave the following error.
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
    Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
    402 |                                 onChange={handlePO_status}
    403 |                             >
  > 404 |                                 <MenuItem let value={true}>Yes</MenuItem>
        |                                               ^^^^^
    405 |                                 <MenuItem value={false}>No</MenuItem>
    406 |                             </Select>
    407 |                         </FormControl>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just pass it as string e.g. `value="true"` then you can just check `value === 'true'`.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me and it actually preserves the `boolean` type in the underlying form state as well (in Material-UI v5).

```
<MenuItem value={true as any}>True</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={false as any}>False</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error - the type `value` expects is `string | number | readonly string[] | undefined`. As such, you cannot pass a boolean into the `value` property.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish from your code snippet, but you may need to reconsider the structure of your code. For example,

```js
<MenuItem onClick={() => handlePO_status(true)}>Yes</MenuItem>
<MenuItem onClick={() => handlePO_status(false)}>No</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error trying to get working something like this:

```
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState<boolean>()
const menuItems = [{id:"0", label: "YES", value: true},{id:"1", label: "NO", value: false}]
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
setSomeValue(e.target.value)
}
...
<TextField
select
value={someValue}
onChange={handleChange}>
{menuItems.map((item) => (
<MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.value}>{item.label}</MenuItem>
))}
</TextField>
```

The problem is the line value={item.value} because MUI MenuItem does not accept boolean value, only string or number. I found the following solution - I used the type string intead of boolean in menu definition const and had to adjust handleChange to return not a string but boolean. Then someValue datatype is not affected, is still boolean and desired functionality is working. This worked for me at least. So the working code looks like this:

```
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState<boolean>()
const menuItems = [{id:"0", label: "YES", value: "true"},{id:"1", label: "NO", value: "false"}]
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
setSomeValue(e.target.value === "true" ? true : false)
}
...
<TextField
select
value={someValue}
onChange={handleChange}>
{menuItems.map((item) => (
<MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.value}>{item.label}</MenuItem>
))}
</TextField>
```

Comment: I don't think this is perfect because the currently selected item won't be rendered as such (true is not "true")